# I accidentally stirred all the lees into my wine during first racking. Now (1 day later) secondary has lots (+1cm) of sediment. Should I rack again?

Tags: wine, racking, lees

Making some kiwi wine (exciting!). When transferring from primary to secondary getting the fruit pulp was a bit of a mess and I inevitably stirred all the lees into the wine. Now, after only 1 day in the secondary there is lots of sediment in the carboy (more than 1cm). Should I worry about it at all? Rack it again of the gunk?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry. This is why we do multiple rackings when we make wine. You'll have to do it again in a couple of months. Just keep your sulfite levels up.

Comment: Can you elaborate about the sulfates?

Comment: Sulfites. They are different that sulfates. They are a preservative and have been used in wine for thousands of years. https://blog.eckraus.com/adding-sulfites-to-homemade-wine

Comment: Ah, ok that makes sense. I didn't add suflites into this batch at all. Should I do it now ~5 days into the secondary?

Comment: Yes add it now.

Answer (score 1):

Time will give you clear wine, multiple rackings may be required.  However, if you are anxious for a clear product (not necessarily sufficiently aged), you may wish to investigate a clearing agent.  I have tried many over the years, but Super-Kleer, a two stage clearing agent, has rendered anything I've used it on perfectly crystal clear.